# Saxon error in XSLT using parse-xml-fragment in .NET

Tags: .net, xslt, saxon

I get the following error whenever I use parse-xml-fragment in our transforms.

```
First argument to parse-xml-fragment() is not a well-formed and 
namespace-well-formed XML fragment. 
XML parser reported: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser not found 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
```

Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="bob">
        <greeting>
            <xsl:copy-of select="fn:parse-xml-fragment('&lt;hello&gt;Ted&lt;/hello&gt;')"/>
        </greeting>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <bob>&lt;hello&gt;Burt&lt;/hello&gt;</bob>
</root>
```

This is the output we get when testing in in XmlSpy using the built in engine, which we're using to verify our transforms, and produces exactly what I'd expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <greeting xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <hello>Ted</hello>
</greeting>
```

I've tried using CDATA instead, but get the same error.

I've tried using Saxon 9.6.0.6 (version we were using), 9.6.0.10 (latest 9.6 branch), and 9.7.0.14 (latest stable 9.7 branch), all from NuGet, all running under .NET 4.6, with the following code:

```
    public static void Run(Uri samplesDir)
    {
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(samplesDir, "test.xml"));

        XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(samplesDir, "test.xslt")).Load();

        transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

        Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
        serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);

        transformer.Run(serializer);
    }
```

This is a very slightly modified version of the Saxon samples; I've also tried using my company's .NET integration of Saxon with the same result.  A colleague has tried the same via Java and it works without error.

Is the XSLT at fault here?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure `parse-xml-fragment` was supported in any 9.6 release, http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.6/functions/fn/ does not list it. I think it should work in 9.7, I have tried your sample with Saxon 9.7 EE .NET from the command line and it works. I also tried with Saxon 9.7 HE .NET from the command line and it also works.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I haven't tried via the command line so I'll try that. Perhaps the issue is with the NuGet installation?  NB: a moot point as I can use either version, but this indicates 9.6 should work http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/parse-xml-fragment.html

Comment: I have now tried to run your .NET code with VS 2015 and Saxon 9.7 HE and I get the error you indicate. I am not sure what the `Transform.exe` does differently, you might want to ask in the Saxon support forum or need to wait until they pick it up here.

Comment: I have raised this as a (possible) Saxon bug at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3101. Please follow that tracker to be notified of eventual resolution. The strategy for getting a default parser on .NET is a bit different between the C# API and the command line because with the API, integration with Microsoft technologies is required and this is not the case on the command line.

Comment: Bug saxonica.plan.io/issues/3101 has been resolved. 
The class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser. seems not to be supported under IKVM even though it is in the standard Java distribution.

A fix has been applied in the class ParseXmlFragment. Here we make a call to the configuration to create the apache XML Parser. Fix available in the next maintenance release of 9.7